# Como ativar o LogCat ?

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

Olá, eu estou fazendo uma app em que uso o AlarmManager, preciso utilizar o LogCat mas não sei como fazer ele aparecer no Android Studio.

Answer (score 2):

Geralmente o LogCat aparece na parte inferior do Android Studio, na aba Android Monitor.
[image: localização do logcat]

Tente pressionar **ALT+6** no Windows ou **CMD+6** no caso de Mac

Comment: Muito obrigado!